# Will the sticky keys' method work for bypassing Windows 8 passwords?

Tags: windows-8, passwords

I haven't bought Windows 8, but I'm interested in a question.

From Windows XP to Windows 7 (almost 12 years and maybe more), Windows had a great "bug" for [bypassing passwords - sticky keys](http://4sysops.com/archives/forgot-the-administrator-password-the-sticky-keys-trick/).

So I'm interested in a question. Will that work on Windows 8? Or has Microsoft fixed one of the biggest security holes in Windows?

Comment: Raymond Chen calls these sorts of "vulnerabilities" ["being on the other side of the airtight hatchway"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/08/07/4268706.aspx). If you can replace Sticky Keys you can do anything you want anyway.

Comment: File under "Not really a vulnerability."

Comment: PEOPLE, That's why I said "they, who don't know that, please don't answer".Read this and please, get back your DOWNVOTES!!, if you don't know about this famous bug.
http://4sysops.com/archives/forgot-the-administrator-password-the-sticky-keys-trick/

Comment: @SEARAS - easy, I just made a comment which seemed funny to me at the moment. I didn't downvote. I know what are sticky keys, and a 5 sec google search for "sticky keys password crack" gave me some background on what you are talking about. Besides, downvotes are about the quality of the question. You complain about people not understanding sticky keys, who should stay away... but you don't really try to explain or give context yourself, you just say "go away".

Comment: You can still run `.exe` files in Windows 8, so.... yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's still there, but it's no big deal, since you can always disable Sticky Keys manually

Comment: -1 since this is not a vulnerability.